# Speeding Up BufferedWriter

Tags: java, performance, file, file-system, io

Are there any possible speed improvements I can make to the following method. It takes a JDBC ResultSet and breaks it into several CSV files:

```
public static void convertToCSV(final ResultSet rs) throws SQLException, IOException {
    final DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd,HH:mm:ss");
    format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/UTC"));
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while (rs.next()) {
        final File file = new File(sb.append(rs.getString("FIELD1")).append(".csv").toString());
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }
        final BufferedWriter fw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(), true));
        fw.write(rs.getString("FIELD2"));
        fw.write(',');
        fw.write(rs.getString("FIELD3"));
        fw.write(',');
        final String clobValue = rs.getString("FIELD4");
        if(clobValue==null)
            fw.write("null,");
        else{
            fw.write('\"');
            fw.write(clobValue);
            fw.write("\",");
        }
        final Date date = new Date(rs.getLong("FIELD5"));
        fw.write(format.format(date));
        fw.write('\n');
        fw.close();
        sb.setLength(0);
    }
    rs.close();
}
```

Comment: I assume that field 1 always contains a valid filename, and fields 2, 3, and 4 never contain quote characters or comma characters?

Comment: @EricStein Correct.

Comment: Is there a specific reason for using `Etc/UTC` over just `UTC`?

Comment: @lealand I always thought Etc/UTC was just the standard way of writing it.

Comment: @JohnRoberts I've been looking into it over the past couple of days and I think you're correct. Apparently plain UTC is outdated now (don't have the citation on me though). My ears perk when I see `Etc` though because I think with Java that means a [nautical time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nautical_time), which is the opposite of what you would think.

Answer (score 2):

You *may* see a performance increase by adding multithreading support. For each row, create an instance of a custom `Runable` that takes the five values and add it to a `ThreadPoolExecutor`. You can futz around with the size of the pool. As with all performance enhancements, you'll need to test, test, test to make sure you're seeing a real benefit, and you'll really need to test on a production clone for it to have any meaning. It may not make a difference on your local machine but be a big help on production, or vice versa.

Your use of the `StringBuilder` as opposed to just concatenation is probably not doing you any good. Compilers will do that work, and the code is harder to read as-is. There are other things to pick at, but none of them are performance-related.

Comment: Hmm. I've always thought that multi-threading is something to be avoided when writing to disk, especially since I'm using a standard RAID. Might I not see a performance degradation from that?

Comment: @JohnRoberts You certainly might. I am not a performance expert. Hence the emphasis on 'may'. I believe it depends on the number of disks you have and the size of the clobs you're writing. Test, test, test! :-)

Comment: My shoot-from-the-hip thought is that you shouldn't worry about performance degradation from  multithreading. Just the other day I implemented multithreading to make use of my cores when processing multiple files and my runtime was cut by at least a third. You have at least thousand threads running on your OS, all doing their own thing. I would be surprised if at this point the hardware wasn't optimized for exactly this.

Comment: Do note that the parse method of `SimpleDateFormat` isn't thread safe. This doesn't make a difference in your code because it's instanced on each method invocation, but it you ever extract it to a constant, you'l run into to whole bunch of problems.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Java 7, you should use [`try-with-resources`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) on the `BufferedWriter` instance for safe and efficient I/O management.

Since you only use your `StringBuilder` once to create the filename, you can also consider simple `String` concatenation:

```
File file = new File(rs.getString("FIELD1") + ".csv");
```

This is a trade-off between one `StringBuilder` instance, and *slight improvement* in readability. :)

Instead of calling `fw.write()` a number of times, you can also consider constructing the output `String` first. Then, if you happen to be on Java 8, you can consider using [`Collectors.joining(CharSequence)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining-java.lang.CharSequence-) to join the `Stream` of output values you need as such:

```
// using Java 8's optional to slightly simplify the transformation
String clobValue = Optional.ofNullable(rs.getString("FIELD4"))
                            .map(v -> "\"" + v + "\"").orElse(null);
String date = format.format(new Date(rs.getLong("FIELD5")));
String output = Arrays.asList(rs.getString("FIELD2"), rs.getString("FIELD3"), 
                    clobValue, date).stream().collect(Collectors.joining(","));
fw.append(output).newLine();
```

Finally, I concur with [@EricStein](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/108180/24141)'s answer that you may want to consider multi-threading if you really need to go [*up to 11*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Up_to_eleven). On this note, you may then want to apply a simple model class for the values from the `ResultSet` object so that you can handle the multi-threading from a `List<FileContent>` instead. For example:

```
public static List<FileContent> map(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException, IOException {
    List<FileContent> result = new ArrayList<>();
    while (rs.next()) {
        result.add(mapRow(rs));
    }
    return result;
}

public static void writeToFiles(List<FileContent> list) {
    // Multi-threading handling here, e.g. using CompletableFutures
}
```

Comment: Even if not using Java 7+, all the close statements should be in a `finally` block.